# Merge Pandas dataframes on column, and have result sorted by same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have these two dataframes:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"key":[1,3,5], "columnA":[30,40,50]})
>>> df1
   key  columnA
0    1       30
1    3       40
2    5       50

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"key":[2,4], "columnB":[60,70]})
>>> df2
   key  columnB
0    2       60
1    4       70
```

I basically want a new dataframe, with "key", "columnA", and "columnB", where the corresponding data is "interleaved" from the two above dataframes, correspondingly. I did this:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='outer').astype('Int64')
   key  columnA  columnB
0    1       30     <NA>
1    3       40     <NA>
2    5       50     <NA>
3    2     <NA>       60
4    4     <NA>       70
```

... which comes close - but I want the output to be:

```
   key  columnA  columnB
0    1       30     <NA>
1    2     <NA>       60
2    3       40     <NA>
3    4     <NA>       70
4    5       50     <NA>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is possible use `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='outer').astype('Int64').sort_values('key')` ?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael - that mostly works, except the resulting index column is [0, 3, 1, 4, 2], - and I want [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] as in example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to achieve the expected output.

```
In [778]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='outer').astype('Int64').sort_values('key').reset_index().drop('index',1)
Out[778]: 
   key  columnA  columnB
0    1       30     <NA>
1    2     <NA>       60
2    3       40     <NA>
3    4     <NA>       70
4    5       50     <NA>
```

Or you can pass `ignore_index=True` in the `sort_values` parameter itself:

```
In [795]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='outer').astype('Int64').sort_values('key', ignore_index=True)
Out[795]: 
   key  columnA  columnB
0    1       30     <NA>
1    2     <NA>       60
2    3       40     <NA>
3    4     <NA>       70
4    5       50     <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `drop=True` parameter:

```
df = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='outer')
        .astype('Int64')
        .sort_values('key')
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   key  columnA  columnB
0    1       30      NaN
1    2      NaN       60
2    3       40      NaN
3    4      NaN       70
4    5       50      NaN
```